# C++: fstream, reading/writing backwards?

Tags: c++, fstream

first time posting here so I apologize if I make any errors.
Essentially, I want to know if you can use ifstream.read(addr, size) where size is a negative number. As far as I know, size is a signed argument and the tell/seek commands have similar functionality.
Example:

```
ifstream fin(argv[1], ios::binary | ios::ate);
fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bmp), -(sizeof(bmp)));
```

Comment: not definitive but [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamsize) says "negative values of std::streamsize are never used"

Comment: No, the value is "number of bytes to read", so perhaps read -5 would mean write them back? Seriously, you can seek -5 bytes before the read.